# Executing an executable must be done using a path. Why?

Tags: unix

In the following:

```
Roberts-MacBook-Pro:Code robertnash$ mkdir Flag
Roberts-MacBook-Pro:Code robertnash$ cd Flag/
Roberts-MacBook-Pro:Flag robertnash$ swift package init --type executable
Roberts-MacBook-Pro:Flag robertnash$ swift build
Compile Swift Module 'Flag' (1 sources)
Linking ./.build/debug/Flag
```

In order to execute the executable, it must be a path, like so

```
Roberts-MacBook-Pro:Flag robertnash$ .build/debug/Flag
Hello, world!
```

If I go to where 'Flag' is located, the command cannot be run by simply typing 'Flag'.

```
Roberts-MacBook-Pro:Flag robertnash$ cd .build
Roberts-MacBook-Pro:.build robertnash$ cd debug
Roberts-MacBook-Pro:debug robertnash$ Flag
-bash: Flag: command not found
```

It must be a path, like so.

```
Roberts-MacBook-Pro:debug robertnash$ ./Flag
```

Why is that ?

Comment: It is not related to Swift in any way. It is a standard Unix security measure. The current directory is not, by default, in the `$PATH` environment variable. `$PATH` contains a list of paths where executable programs are searched when the user types only the program name, without a path.

Comment: Thanks for the response @axiac. Have updated the tags of this post. Feel free to post this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `export PATH="$PATH:."` then it will add the current working directory to your path and you won't need the `./` prefix.  (Most (all?) shells accept just a trailing colon without the dot, but I find it's more explicit about what it does.)

This isn't present by default because it is a security risk: a malicious script could be named as something missing from your path, like `nmap` or even as a typo like `sl`, and placed in a directory in the hopes that you run it.  Forcing you to prefix `./` is a good way of avoiding that.